# How to set Swiping control for landscape orientation in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set swiping control for landscape orientation, for potrait orientation i'm using below code.Please help to work this in landscape orientation.

TouchPoint _first;

```
    private List<TList> _pivotList;
    public Pivot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += pivot_Loaded;
        Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
    }
```

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)

{
    TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(null);

```
if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
    _first = mainTouch;
else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up)
{
    var xDelta = mainTouch.Position.X - _first.Position.X;
    var yDelta = Math.Abs(mainTouch.Position.Y - _first.Position.Y);
    if (yDelta > Math.Abs(xDelta))
        return;
    if (Math.Abs(xDelta - 0) > 10)
    {
        var currentIndex = pivotList.SelectedIndex;
        int noOfPivotItems = pivotList.Items.Count;
        currentIndex = (xDelta < 0) ?
            ++currentIndex % noOfPivotItems :
            (--currentIndex + noOfPivotItems) % noOfPivotItems;
        pivotList.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what you already have found out. At first sight it seems like you run out of memory.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the full 100 pages in memory? Try only keeping the 5 previous and 5 next pages in memory.

Comment: any example because i'm new to this windows phone devlopment

Comment: I don't have a development environment near me, but try to swap pages in and out when you swipe your pivotList. Say, each time you swipe (that'll be an event i think), you keep 5 previous (currentIndex -5) and 5 following (currentIndex +5) items loaded.